# Is there a batch size limit to CreateBatchWrite()

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

When attempting to upload ~30,000 users into a dynamodb table using the Amazon.DynamoDBv2 wrapper for .net, not all records made it, however, there was no exception either.

```
 var userBatch = _context.CreateBatchWrite<Authentication_User>();
 userBatch.AddPutItems(users);
 userBatch.ExecuteAsync();
```

Approximately 2,500'ish records were written to the table. Has anyone found a limit to number or size of batch inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetDynamoDBContext.BatchOperations.html) (emphasis mine):

> When using the object persistence model, you can specify **any number of operations** in a batch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out as I had overlooked the NOTE: part. I think this was just an early exit and not Waiting on the async call to finish. Doh!

Comment: After waiting on the thread and about 10K records in, I got an Provision Exceeded  Exception. Your answer helped me solve, I had to adjust the ProvisionedThroughput.

Answer (score 0):

I exited the process after the return from ExecuteAsync(). That was the problem. When I let it run I can see the data slowly build up. However, in the bulk insert I used a Task.Wait() because there was nothing to do until the records had been loaded. However, Iridium's answer above assited me with the second issue that revolved around ProvisionedThroughput exceptions.